# Remove description / information when starting octave

Tags: octave

Everytime I run octave, the following description/information displays on the screen, is there anyway the following doesn't shows up..

```
{

GNU Octave, version 3.8.1
Copyright (C) 2014 John W. Eaton and others.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".

Additional information about Octave is available at http://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit http://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read http://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

}
```

PS: I also added 'clc' to the octaverc file, but the information still shows up for some split seconds, and it bothers me.

Answer (score 0):

from command line help

```
$ octave --help
....
 --silent, --quiet, -q   Don't print message at startup.
```

and so

```
$ octave -q
octave:1>
```